# Sendto fails with an error "no such device or address" after sometime

Tags: c, linux, raw-sockets

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct sockaddr_in src_socket_address, dest_socket_address;
    struct ifreq ifreq_i;
    struct ifreq if_mac;
    struct ifreq ifreq_ip;
    int packet_size;
    char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];
    char sendbuf[BUF_SIZE];

    int tx_len = 0;
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(65536);

    int sock = socket (AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));

    int send_soc = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);

    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr*)sendbuf;
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    struct sockaddr_ll sadr_ll;
    int saddr_len = sizeof(saddr);
    /*Get interface name*/

    if(argc < 1) {
        strcpy(ifName, argv[1]);
    } else {
        strcpy(ifName, DEFAULT_IF);
    }


    if(sock < 0) {
        printf("Failed to create socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(send_soc < -1) {
        printf("Failed to create socket send");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Get the index of the interface to send on */
    memset(&ifreq_i, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(ifreq_i.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);

    if((ioctl(send_soc, SIOCGIFINDEX, (void*)&ifreq_i)) < 0){
        printf("Error in index ioctl reading %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(send_soc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 

    }

    /*Get the mac address of the interface*/
    memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);

    if((ioctl(send_soc, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac)) <0){

        printf("Error in SIOCGIFHWADDR ioctl reading %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(send_soc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*Get the ip address of the interface"
    memset(&ifreq_ip, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(ifreq_ip.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);

    if((ioctl(send_soc, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifreq_ip)) <0)
        printf("error in SIOCGIFADDR ip address reading\n");*/

    while (1) {
        packet_size = recvfrom(sock, buffer, 65536, 0, &saddr, (socklen_t*)&saddr_len);
        if(packet_size == -1) {
            printf("Failed to get packets\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("Received packets");
        }

        // struct iphdr *ip_packet = (struct iphdr*)buffer;
        // memset(&src_socket_address, 0, sizeof(src_socket_address));
        // src_socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = ip_packet->saddr;
        // memset(&dest_socket_address, 0, sizeof(dest_socket_address));
        // dest_socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = ip_packet->daddr;



        memset(sendbuf, 0, BUF_SIZE);

        /*Construct ethernet header*/

        eth->h_source[0] = (unsigned char)(if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0]);
        eth->h_source[1] = (unsigned char)(if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1]);
        eth->h_source[2] = (unsigned char)(if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2]);
        eth->h_source[3] = (unsigned char)(if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3]);
        eth->h_source[4] = (unsigned char)(if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4]);
        eth->h_source[5] = (unsigned char)(if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5]);

        /*filling destination mac address*/
         eth->h_dest[0] = DESTMAC0;
         eth->h_dest[1] = DESTMAC1;
         eth->h_dest[2] = DESTMAC2;
         eth->h_dest[3] = DESTMAC3;
         eth->h_dest[4] = DESTMAC4;
         eth->h_dest[5] = DESTMAC5;

         eth->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_IP);

         /* end of ethernet header*/
         tx_len += sizeof(struct ethhdr);

         /*Packet data for dummy data*/
         sendbuf[tx_len++] = 0xAA;
         sendbuf[tx_len++] = 0xBB;
         sendbuf[tx_len++] = 0xCC;
         sendbuf[tx_len++] = 0xDD;
         sendbuf[tx_len++] = 0xEE;

         sadr_ll.sll_ifindex = ifreq_i.ifr_ifindex;
         sadr_ll.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;

         sadr_ll.sll_addr[0] = DESTMAC0;
         sadr_ll.sll_addr[1] = DESTMAC1;
         sadr_ll.sll_addr[2] = DESTMAC2;
         sadr_ll.sll_addr[3] = DESTMAC3;
         sadr_ll.sll_addr[4] = DESTMAC4;
         sadr_ll.sll_addr[5] = DESTMAC5;

         /* Send Packet */

         if (sendto(send_soc, buffer, packet_size, 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&sadr_ll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) < 0) {
            printf("Sending packet failed\n");
            close(send_soc);
         } else {
            printf("Sending packet successful");
         }

        printf("================================================\n");
    }
    close(send_soc);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to receive ethernet packets using raw sockets and duplicate the packets to send to another port in the same machine to analyse the traffic. I can receive the packets however after a while I get an error while sending the packets as "No such device or address".

Can you please explain whats the problem here?

Thanks!
Nivetha

Comment: I think - but am not sure - that raw packet support requires root permissions, though I would have expected it to fail when the socket was created, not when it was used. Might this point you in a useful direction?

Comment: I did run the code with sudo permissions. It receives and send packets. But fails after sometime.

Comment: Few initial thoughts. You do not use `struct sockaddr` to define storage, the correct one to use is `struct sockaddr_storage`. Secondly, `ioctl` calls are often work not as expected, I would output what they return, especially if you rely on that return in following code. Finally, I do not see where `DESTMACX` guys are defined.

Comment: Hi wick! I have defined the DESTMACs upfront. Not seen in this code snippet though.

Comment: Also, after sometime, I see "segmentation fault" or "Message too long"